# Are all these sentences correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, grammaticality

1) I will notify you once we receive the parcel

2)I will notify you once we have received the parcel

3) I will notify you once the parcel has been received.

3) I will notify you once the parcel is received.

Answer (score -1):

They are all correct, but some are preferred depending on the intent. 
3) and (supposed to be 4) use passive voice, which is generally less desirable. Although in 3) and 4?) the parcel could be received by someone other that "we", so they may be appropriate. 
1) Conveys more urgency: The notification will happen as soon as we receive the parcel.
2) Implies some time may elapse between the parcel arrival and the notification.

Comment: Thank you Gorlux for the detailed explanation. That was really helpful. Much appreciated.